# How to get only a particular type of elements from a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm studying [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/), and in Chapter 10 (Folding Lists), I'm trying to solve an exercise regarding getting only one particular type of element from a list that includes different types of elements.

The authors give the following code:

```
import Data.Time

data DatabaseItem = DbString String
                  | DbNumber Integer
                  | DbDate   UTCTime
                  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

theDatabase :: [DatabaseItem]
theDatabase = [ DbDate (UTCTime
                        (fromGregorian 1911 5 1)
                        (secondsToDiffTime 34123))
              , DbNumber 9001
              , DbString "Hello, world!"
              , DbDate (UTCTime
                        (fromGregorian 1921 5 1)
                        (secondsToDiffTime 34123))
              ]
```

and the first question is:

> Write a function that filters for DbDate values and returns a list of
>   the UTCTime values inside them.

```
filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate = undefined
```

Since the chapter is all about folding lists, I assume it can be done using, for example, `foldr`.

My initial attempt has been to first write some helper functions and use them in a `foldr`, such as:

```
getDbDate1 :: DatabaseItem -> UTCTime
getDbDate1 (DbDate utcTime) = utcTime

isDbDate :: DatabaseItem -> Bool
isDbDate (DbDate _) = True
isDbDate _ = False

filterDbDate1 :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate1 database = foldr ((:) . getDbDate1) [] (filter isDbDate database)
```

This seems to do the job, because:

```
λ> filterDbDate1 theDatabase
[1911-05-01 09:28:43 UTC,1921-05-01 09:28:43 UTC]
```

But I'm not comfortable with this solution, because first of all, it gives the following warning:

```
/Users/emre/code/haskell/chapter10_folding_lists/database.hs:36:1: Warning: …
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘getDbDate1’:
        Patterns not matched:
            DbString _
            DbNumber _
```

And I'm using two helper functions, one to help with filtering out the values that are not DbDate, another to get at the `UTCTime` component.

So, to get rid of non-exhaustive pattern matching warning and use a single helper function, I've decided to write it like:

```
getDbDate2 :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe UTCTime
getDbDate2 (DbDate utcTime) = Just utcTime
getDbDate2 _ = Nothing

filterDbDate2 :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate2 database = foldr ((:) . getDbDate2) [] database
```

But, of course, the above does not compile, because it does not type check, because, for example:

```
λ> foldr ((:) . getDbDate2) [] theDatabase
[Just 1911-05-01 09:28:43 UTC,Nothing,Nothing,Just 1921-05-01 09:28:43 UTC]
```

In other words, it can return a list of `Just UTCTime` values, together with `Nothing` values, and not only a list of `UTCTime` values.

So my question is: how can I write a (helper?) function that, in one go (so that I don't have to use the `filter`), checks if its value is `DbNumber`, and if so returns the `UTCTime` component? (And if not... it also has to return something (e.g. `Nothing`?), and this is where I'm having trouble, that is using `Maybe UTCTime`, and then getting `Just UTCTime` values, etc.)

Comment: [`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) can help out here.

Comment: The function `f = maybe [] (:[]) . getDbDate2` returns a singleton list of the time when there is one, and an empty list otherwise. `filterDbDate` is then simply `foldMap f`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several other answers here covering good suggestions about *other* ways to think about the problem: using `catMaybes` to munge the data a second time after picking out `Maybe UTCTime`s; using list comprehensions and the handy syntax they have for filtering out non-matching patterns; using the monadic structure of lists to include or skip results; and writing a bespoke recursive function. In this answer, I will address your direct question, showing how to use the program structure you already have without completely rethinking your approach to list manipulations -- calling `foldr` with a helper function that does everything you need in one go.

First of all, I observe that all your existing attempts send `foldr` a function which unconditionally calls `(:)`:

```
foldr ((:) . getDbDate1) [] (filter isDbDate database)
foldr ((:) . getDbDate2) [] database
```

The thing about this pattern is that this means the list you get out of the `foldr` will have the same length as the function you pass in -- since every `(:)` in the input list gets turned into a `(:)` in the output list. In your first solution, you handled this by removing some entries you didn't care about from the input list; in your second solution, you handled this by having extra uninteresting elements in your output list.

A third solution is to look at the list element before deciding whether to call `(:)` or not. Here is how one might do that:

```
conditionalCons :: DatabaseItem -> [UTCTime] -> [UTCTime]
conditionalCons (DbDate t) ts = t:ts
conditionalCons _          ts =   ts
```

Note in particular that in the second clause, we do not call `(:)` -- this filters out the non-matching elements of the list. We also have no concern about missing patterns. Now we can write

```
filterDbDate3 :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate3 = foldr conditionalCons []
```

Testing it in ghci:

```
> filterDbDate3 theDatabase
[1911-05-01 09:28:43 UTC,1921-05-01 09:28:43 UTC]
```

Perfect!

Comment: I selected this as 'the' answer because of pedagogical reasons. I also liked the answer by @Phyx because it is very close to what the book explained so far (also forcing to focus on types). Nikita-Volkov also gave an answer that I more or less understand but I still haven't come to the Monad chapter in the book (and have no idea what MonadPlus is). The list comprehension answer by Franky is also great, reads just like Python ;) (but again, does not serve very well of my understanding of folding).

Answer (score 9):

A simple list comprehension will do

```
filterDbDate xs = [ x | DbDate x <- xs ]
```

Comment: What if `xs` also contains `DbString`s or `DbNumber`s?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, this list comprehension will still work.

Comment: A list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for a monadic computation. When `DbDate x` matches, it returns `[x]`; otherwise, the `fail` function from the `Monad` class returns an empty list. The concatenation of each of the lists produces the final list, consisting only of `x`s from `DbDate` values.

Answer (score 4):

There are some good answers but I would like to add another approach how you can find solutions to such tasks.

First, **write the simplest possible solution**, i.e. a solution with direct recursion.

```haskell
filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate ((DbDate time):items) = time:(filterDbDate items)
filterDbDate ( _           :items) =       filterDbDate items
```

This helps understand the structures involved and allows you to familiarize yourself with the actual steps needed. It's not the most performant version, but it's easy to write and it's often enough for the task at hand.

The next step would be to **make the code more performant with tail recursion**. It's a simple, almost mechanical transformation.

1. Determine the accumulator type. This is often also the return type; in this case, a list. That gives you the new first lines

   ```haskell
   filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
   filterDbDate = go []
     where ...
   ```
2. Now take the original function and turn it into the internal `go` function by replacing every recursive call with the accumulator and then putting the result into a recursive call to `go`.

   ```haskell
       go acc ((DbDate time):items) = go (time:acc) items
       go acc ( _           :items) = go       acc  items
   ```
3. Add handling of the end case. Beware that the order of operations will be reversed.

   ```haskell
       go acc  []                   = reverse acc
   ```
4. Move the handling of the end case into the original call. This is not necessary if you want to stop here, but it helps on the way to a fold.

   ```haskell
   filterDbDate = reverse . go []
     where 
       go acc  [] = acc
       ...
   ```

Now to **turn that into a fold**. The accumulator is the same the fold will be using and the transformation, again, is almost mechanical.

1. Replace the call to `go` with a call to a fold.

   ```haskell
   filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
   filterDbDate = reverse . foldl f []
   ```
2. Turn `go` into `f` by removing the list-part of the pattern matches, the end case, and the recursive calls.

   ```haskell
     where f acc (DbDate time) = time:acc
           f acc  _            =      acc
   ```
3. Ponder if it would be better to reverse the direction of recursion.

   ```haskell
   filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
   filterDbDate = foldr f []
     where f (DbDate time) = (time:)
           f _             = id
   ```

Now for final cleanup, **extra brownie points** and to enrage Haskell teachers make it as generic as you can without breaking stuff.

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude, GADTs #-}
import ClassyPrelude

filterDbDate :: ( MonoFoldable items, Element items ~ DatabaseItem
                , Monoid times, SemiSequence times, Element times ~ UTCTime)
             => items -> times
filterDbDate = foldr f mempty
   where f (DbDate time) = cons time
         f _             = id
```

Comment: Another excellent and enlightening answer! (Though, right now, I have no idea about NoImplicitPrelude, ClassPrelude, etc. mentioned in the final paragraph. Food for thought. A lot of thought! :)

Comment: @EmreSevinç The default prelude must make some compromises. The ClassyPrelude is one of several alternative ones that tries to choose a different set of compromises for different use cases. You can always do without it (eg *cons* originally comes from Data.Sequences), and it's not the best choice for libraries or teaching but it can be convenient for larger, self-contained applications. The main reason I chose it here is that its authors have thought long and hard about which libraries are used most often in practice, so I can rely on them giving me a useful *cons*.

Answer (score 2):

List is a monad. So we can use the functions of the `Monad` type-class.

```
utcTimes :: [UTCTime]
utcTimes =
  theDatabase >>=
  \ item ->
    case item of
      DbDate utcTime -> [utcTime]
      _ -> []
```

The `(>>=)` function here is the key. It is essentially the same thing as "flatMap" in other languages, if that rings a bell.

The following is the same as the above expressed in the Do-notation:

```
utcTimes :: [UTCTime]
utcTimes =
  do
    item <- theDatabase
    case item of
      DbDate utcTime -> [utcTime]
      _ -> []
```

In fact, we can even generalize this to a function, which will work for any monad over `UTCTime` (well, `MonadPlus`, really):

```
pickUTCTime :: MonadPlus m => DatabaseItem -> m UTCTime
pickUTCTime item =
  case item of
    DbDate utcTime -> return utcTime
    _ -> mzero

utcTimes :: [UTCTime]
utcTimes =
  theDatabase >>= pickUTCTime
```

Comment: That raises the question of whether there is an established way to generically derive functions like `pickUTCTme` for an arbitrary ADT. Perhaps something in the lens library?

Comment: You just need `makePrisms` and you get `_DbDate` ; then `(^? _DbDate) :: DatabaseItem -> Maybe UTCTime` , `toListOf (traverse . _DbDate) :: [DataBaseItem] -> [UTCTime]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is as follows

```
filterDbDate :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate db = filterDbDate' [] db
  where filterDbDate' :: [UTCTime] -> [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
        filterDbDate' rest ((DbDate utcTime):xs) = filterDbDate' (rest ++ [utcTime]) xs
        filterDbDate' rest (_:xs) = filterDbDate' rest xs
        filterDbDate' rest _      = rest
```

That is, you pass along another argument which contains the values you want to keep. If you look closely, you'll see that this is exactly what the type of `foldl` indicates too `foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b` (You can also do it with `foldr`, but I'll leave that to you), except it expects one element at a time. So let's rewrite `filterDbDate'` to do that too.

```
filterDbDate2 :: [DatabaseItem] -> [UTCTime]
filterDbDate2 db = foldl filterDbDate'' [] db
   where filterDbDate'' :: [UTCTime] -> DatabaseItem -> [UTCTime]
         filterDbDate'' rest (DbDate utcTime) = (rest ++ [utcTime])
         filterDbDate'' rest _                = rest
```

This is not the most efficient function, but hopefully you'll see how to translate functions to using folds. Try it with `foldr`!

Answer (score 1):

Let me give my 50cent, even that this thread is too old!
So i make a function to check if the value is DbDate:

```
 isDbDate:: DatabaseItem -> Bool
 isDbDate (DbDate x) = True
 isDbDate  _         = False
```

After that things are simple.

Foldr solution

```
foldr (\x start -> if isDbDate x then x:start else start)  [] theDatabase
```

List comprehension solution.

```
[x |  x <- theDatabase, isDbDate x ]
```